# KdV equation and classical linear wave equation

Tags: wavefunction, solitons, integrable-systems, non-linear-systems

Like we know, the standard form of [KdV equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Korteweg-deVriesEquation.html) is

$$u_{t}-6uu_{x}+u_{xxx}=0,\tag{1}$$

where this equation describes a solitary wave propagation and $u=u(x,t)$.

On the other hand, we know the classical wave equation

$$\frac{{\partial}^{2}u}{{\partial}t^{2}}-\frac{{\partial}^{2}u}{{\partial}x^{2}}=0.\tag{2}$$

My question is: what is the physical difference exhibited by the terms $u_{t}$ and $u_{tt}$ in both equations? I mean, I know (1) is nonlinear what is the physical difference?

What does mean, physically, $u_{t}$ and $u_{tt}$?

Comment: $u_t=\partial u/\partial t$ is simply notation and means the [time derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_derivative) to first, $u_t$, and second, $u_{tt}$ orders.

Comment: Also, this [recent question by BMS](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105802/first-order-wave-equation-why-is-its-presence-not-common) might be useful in seeing the difference between $u_t$ and $u_{tt}$.