# Wave equation in classical mechanics!

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, conventions

> We  represent the wavefunction of any wave on the string as $$y=f(x-vt),$$ where $v$ is velocity of the wave and $x$ is distance from origin and $t$ is time taken to reach the given point and $y$ is the displacement from the the $x$-axis.

but my question is why do we represent wave by this equation (*i have clearly understood that the vertical displacement is the function of distance from the mean origin and time*), why can't we represent a wave function by something like $$y=f(x^2-v^2t^2)$$ or any other function and why is there negative sign between $x$ and $vt$. i think negative sign doesn't make any sense.

on referring other book i saw wave equation was represented as $$y=f(t-\frac{x}{v}),$$ are they both same?

Please try to give answer with simple explanation, i am not expert in differentiation or differential equations, so i can't understand their meanings!

Comment: Perhaps have a look at http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/174862/50583

Comment: @ACuriousMind i edited my question that i don't understand differentiation(*i know very basic of it*)

Comment: @krotov - Sorry to say, but if you are not following along on the math than explaining the why of it isn't going to be very useful. I understand that you might not have gotten to calculus and differential equations. Fear not, if you pursue physics you will! But, in a very simple way, a wave is a 'something' that travels in a given direction with a given velocity. A simple wave will look the same as it moves along (think of waves on the deep ocean - not on the beach!). Thus it _must_ have the functional form y = f(x-vt) - that function looks the same as it moves in x with velocity v.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I answered a very similar question; if I get the time, I'll look out up later this evening.

Comment: Is the yellow block a quote? From where?

Comment: @Qmechanic from my notes

Comment: It's not quite as similar as I thought, but [this is what I was thinking of last night](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105802/25301).

Answer (score 1):

A1: In General, second function is not a solution of wave equation. The general solution is$$y=f(x-vt)+g(x+vt).$$One can show that $$y=f(x^2-v^2 t^2)$$satisfies $x^2 \frac {d^2 y}{dx^2}-t^2\frac {1}{v^2} \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} $ instead of $\frac {d^2 y}{dx^2}-\frac {1}{v^2} \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} $ by using 
[Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).
Moreover, it doesn't mean propagating wave while $$y=f(x-vt)$$
means propagating wave.
A2: The first representation
$$y=f(x-vt)$$
and the third
$$y=f (t-\frac {x}{v})$$
is equivalent since it is just a change of variable.

Comment: you didn't say why negative sign is there in the  equation $f(x-vt)$

Comment: The minus sign just gives a wave traveling to the right.  Use a plus sign and you get a wave traveling to the left.  I think the minus is just a tradition.  Either way is fine.